# C++ Vector of C++ objects to mxArray in mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have the following c++ vector:

```
std::vector<myStruct> myVec;
```

Where myStruct contains:

```
struct myStruct {
  Point3D start;
  Point3D end;
  double lenght;
}
struct Point3D {
  double x, y, z;
}
```

Now in my mex file I would like to convert this into a mxArray while keeping the same structure.

current (non functioning) code:

```
// basic 'out' 
mxArray *out;
mwSize dims[2] = { 1, 1 };
const char *pointField[] = {"point"};
const char *fields[] = {"start", "end","lenght"};
const char *3dFields[] =  {"x", "y", "z"};
out = mxCreateStructArray(2,dims,(int)myVec.size(),pointField);
for( int i = 0 ; i < myVec.size() ; ++i)
{
    // create struct to fill
    mxArray *point = mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, 3, fields);

    // create struct for start
    mxArray *start= mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, 3, 3dFields);
    mxSetField( start, 0, "x", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].start.x) );
    mxSetField( start, 0, "y", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].start.y) );
    mxSetField( start, 0, "z", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].start.z) );

    // create struct for end
    mxArray *end= mxCreateStructArray(2, dims, 3, 3dFields);
    mxSetField( end, 0, "x", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].end.x) );
    mxSetField( end, 0, "y", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].end.y) );
    mxSetField( end, 0, "z", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].end.z) );

    // add start + end to 'point'
    mxSetField( point, 0, "start", start);
    mxSetField( point, 0, "end", end); 
    mxSetField( point, 0, "lenght", mxCreateDoubleScalar(myVec[i].lenght) );

    // add completed 'point' struct to out at given index i
    mxSetField(out, i, "point", point );
}
plhs[0] = out;
```

As you can see, it's important that I can have 1 output value, which can contain multiple "points"-structs of which each point has a start(xyz)-struct, end(xyz)-struct and lenght value.

So far this code only outputs 1 single structure in the correct format, but then for the 2nd iteration, it only creates an empty 'end' value directly at the level where 'point' is.

What do I have to change to have this work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't do what you describe, nor what your MEX code tries to do.  start and end are both vectors of points, rather than single points, and your MEX file tries to access them with accessor functions.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Also consider showing an example of how you want to access the resulting MATLAB struct.  I think you've mixed the code that would give you `myVec.point(17).start.x` vs `myVec(17).point.start.x`, and I think you probably want instead `myVec(17).start.x`.  But I'm just guessing.

Comment: Hi Peter, I adjusted the code as I have it now (it were indeed just Point3D structs, not vectors thereof). My apologies for the initial incorrect code. As for the access afterwards; this function is called from a matlab s-function and the results will have to be accessible there. As to how, I'd be sufficiently happy with just having the ability to go point for point and for each point get the end.x/y/z etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

#### vec_struct.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>

// C++ struct
struct Point3D {
    double x, y, z;
};
struct myStruct {
    Point3D start;
    Point3D end;
    double length;
};

const char *fieldsPoint[] = {"x", "y", "z"};
const char *fieldsStruct[] = {"start", "end", "length"};

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs != 0 || nlhs > 1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:MEX", "Wrong number of arguments.");
    }

    // create C++ vector of structs
    std::vector<myStruct> v;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        myStruct s = {
            {1.0+i, 2.0+i, 3.0+i},
            {4.0+i, 5.0+i, 6.0+i},
            i
        };
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    // convert it to MATLAB struct array and return it as output
    mxArray *p;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, v.size(), 3, fieldsStruct);
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        // start point
        p = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 3, fieldsPoint);
        mxSetField(p, 0, "x", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].start.x));
        mxSetField(p, 0, "y", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].start.y));
        mxSetField(p, 0, "z", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].start.z));
        mxSetField(plhs[0], i, "start", p);

        // end point
        p = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 3, fieldsPoint);
        mxSetField(p, 0, "x", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].end.x));
        mxSetField(p, 0, "y", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].end.y));
        mxSetField(p, 0, "z", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].end.z));
        mxSetField(plhs[0], i, "end", p);

        // length
        mxSetField(plhs[0], i, "length", mxCreateDoubleScalar(v[i].length));
    }
}
```

We compile and call the MEX-function from MATLAB:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims vec_struct.cpp
>> s = vec_struct()
s = 
1x10 struct array with fields:
    start
    end
    length
```

As you can see, this creates a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html) of length 10. For instance the 5th structure is accessed as:

```
>> s(5)
ans = 
     start: [1x1 struct]
       end: [1x1 struct]
    length: 4
>> s(5).start
ans = 
    x: 5
    y: 6
    z: 7
>> s(5).start.x
ans =
     5
```

---

The above MEX-file is equivalent to the following MATLAB code:

```
ss = struct();
for i=1:10
    ss(i).start  = struct('x',1+i-1, 'y',2+i-1, 'z',3+i-1);
    ss(i).end    = struct('x',4+i-1, 'y',5+i-1, 'z',6+i-1);
    ss(i).length = i-1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues (not necessarily complete):

1. `out` is created as a scalar structure in your code, instead it should probably be

   `out = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, (int)myVec.size(), 3, pointField);`
2. You specify `const char *fields[] = {"start", "end","depth"};` but then you try to set the `lenght` field.

The first issue might be the reason for your observation - in mex you'll have to pre-allocate the structure matrix appropriately.

Comment: Fixed the field error "depth" should indeed have been "lenght". Thanks! I will try out the CreateStructMatrix to see if it solves my problem:)

Comment: CreateStructMatrix isn't the important difference.  The important difference is the dimensions of the array, which here is 1xN, rather than 1x1 with N fields.